# syntax error, unexpected 'DB_PASSWORD' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php on line 4

Tags: apache2, localhost, syntax

I have received this error message in the log file */var/log/apache2/error.log*
syntax error, unexpected 'DB_PASSWORD' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php on line 4
Following the installation of wordpress, I had put in the password when creating the user wordpress. Can you tell me how I can unravel this issue; as when looking in the file *config-localhost.php* there appears to be no syntax error:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress;);
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'changed');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content');
?>
```

Comment: It looks like `'DB_USER', 'wordpress;);` has a `;` in place of the closing `'`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a syntax error in the line before:

```
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress;);
```

The string `wordpress` is never closed, so the whole rhythm is out of whack, so to speak. It's quite common that the actual reason for a syntax error isn't in the line where the interpreter stumbles (here the `DB_PASSWORD` setting), but a bit before that.

Comment: Much appreciated! -It's done the trick!